# Where does the logic go for deciding on which DAO to use (hard drive cache vs remote database)?

Tags: java, design-patterns, dao

Currently, I have 2 DAOs for creating `DayActivity` objects:

- one getting the objects from the local hard drive (cached between sessions)
- one getting the objects from a remote database

I am limited to the number of calls I can make to the database and the size limitation for each query, hence relying on a cache between sessions. I have kept the code for each of these DAO separate, since they each are getting the information from separate locations.

What I want to do now is create a DAO(would it be?) for getting a range of `DayActivities`, where some of them are *cached* and some are from the remote, depending on some conditions.

- Is it common for a "DAO" to use mix sources (I would have thought not because then it would mean combining the logic for each)?
- Should I just be putting the logic to decide where the data is coming from elsewhere without thinking of a particular pattern? (I wouldn't have thought this would be the situation since this relies on the rest of the code knowing the actual implementation of the storage)
- Should I be using another design pattern instead?
- Or, is there another option I haven't considered?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It sounds like you are trying to implement your own data caching layer. Are you using a framework like Hibernate or JPA that has cache support built-in? If so, I would look into using that. Even if you are writing plain JDBC calls, I would recommend building a simple cache layer that leverages something like EHCache or Redis to perform all the heavy lifting. These solutions will be much faster than reading/writing files on disk, and will provide mechanisms for cache expiration, data integrity and scalability.

As for performing a query that reads some objects from the DB and some from cache, that doesn't sound like a common pattern. If the entire data set is coming back from a single SQL query, then a cache layer would just cache that entire result so that subsequent identical queries wouldn't have to go back to the database. If however you are doing some sort of loop that performs a separate query for each object, then a cache layer would prevent you from hitting the database for any objects you have already retrieved. Generally though, it is usually much faster to run a single DB query that returns all objects than to run multiple queries.

Comment: I was looking for the concept of a caching layer! I described the system in a poor simplified way, which is really an obscure database issue. The issue that I'm having is that I have a limited number of database calls per hour (150) and I am limited to the calls that I can make, so I need a persistent cache between sessions (a session every 15 minutes would have to do more than 150 calls.)

Comment: Out of curiosity, what database service are you using that only allows 150 queries per hour?

Comment: The service is Java DB but is managed by a 3rd party, I'm not sure how they've implemented this limit.